# mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: server, mysql

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

After running commands
$sudo apt install -f

$sudo apt update

$sudo apt upgrade

$sudo apt install sql-server

i got this

```
**Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt install -f**
[sudo] password for democ67: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client mysql-community-client mysql-community-server
  mysql-community-test mysql-server:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 532 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 235068 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-community-test (5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) ...
Removing mysql-community-server (5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) ...
Removing mysql-client (5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) ...
Removing mysql-community-client (5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) ...
Removing mysql-server:i386 (5.7.19-1ubuntu17.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...


**Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt update**
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease  
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release    
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]      
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:13 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:15 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease                    
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release           
  404  Not Found
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:18 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial InRelease
Get:19 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [2,802 B]  
Get:20 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [25.3 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [305 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [209 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.0 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [57.0 kB]
Get:28 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease [23.5 kB]
Get:29 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages [7,439 B]
Reading package lists... Error!                                                
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:2
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted


**Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  slack-desktop
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 51.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 slack-desktop amd64 2.8.0 [51.2 MB]
Fetched 51.2 MB in 1min 19s (645 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 220470 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../slack-desktop_2.8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slack-desktop (2.8.0) over (2.7.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up slack-desktop (2.8.0) ...


**Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.19-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do `sudo apt install -f`, then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @george i tried these commands but still it is not working. you can see output of these commands in edited part of my question.

Comment: Please open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and fix the error there use the given line numbers

Comment: can you suggest how to fix those errors because I read that but I don't know how to fix them?

Comment: You have a lot of duplicate values in those files as seen in your error message open with `sudo nano` after `cd` into `etc/apt/sources.list.d` and add `#` in front of lines that have more than one entry